# How to convert a string with "Ã¢" and "Ã|" to normal characters like "á" and "ã"? C++

Tags: c++, encoding

So i already asked a few question around this subject and after a week i still didn't resolved that.

I am using c++ not ( c++11) and i when i type a word in a chat box i'm receiving it in another encoding or something like: tãpe turns into "tÃ£pe". The thing i tough is that i could like make an array of all "a" strange caracters could turn like "Ã¢" and etc and then turn then into "a" and even that didn't feel right it didn't worked.

After searching a lot it seems like a multi-byte string is trying to be readed by a single-byte string or something like that.

I can't change nothing before i get this screwed string cause it comes from a server and i need to make it right so i can't work with it on the code.

I would be really pleased if anyone could help me convert that in c++ cause i searched a lot of forums and posts and i didn't find a way to work with this on c++.

Really thanks

I tried using this function but im getting an error:

```
std::string substr(std::string originalString, int maxLength)
{
    std::string resultString = originalString;

    int len = 0;
    int byteCount = 0;

    const char* aStr = originalString.c_str();

    while(*aStr)
    {
        if( (*aStr & 0xc0) != 0x80 )
            len += 1;

        if(len>maxLength)
        {
            resultString = resultString.substr(0, byteCount);
            break;
        }
        byteCount++;
        aStr++;
    }

    return resultString;
}
```

The error is error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class _STL::basic_string,class _STL::allocator > __thiscall kingMobile::KingChatFilter::substr(class _STL::basic_string,class _STL::allocator >,int)" (?substr@KingChatFilter@kingMobile@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DV?$char_traits@D@_STL@@V?$allocator@D@2@@_STL@@V34@H@Z)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is still the same. "Text" in a computer is a sequence of bytes; it's interpretation requires a mapping from bytes to characters. ASCII is such a mapping, as is Latin-1 and UTF-8.

So, `tãpe` does not turn into `tÃ£pe`. They are two ways of looking at the same bytes, UTF-8 and Latin-1 respectively.

Also, the error you show does not come from the code you show. The error clearly comes from code that defines a class or namespace `kingMobile`. Remove that.

Comment: So how can i work with that? Something i should set in code or the IDE?

Comment: @user3481379: I think you're in over your head. You probably should learn C++ basics first - compiling the right file is entirely unrelated to UTF-8

Comment: The problem is that i entered in really big project i cant change the compiling encoding... i dont know what to do

Comment: I changed my character set from unicode to multi-byte in the project configurations but the problem persists

Comment: @user3481379: Those two changes wouldn't help the least. The compiling encoding is for string literals in your program, and the Unicode character set affects `<windows.h>`.

Comment: Any other thing i can do